# How to clear tmux and zsh history with one keypress?

Tags: zsh, tmux

How to clear both tmux history (`tmux clear-history`) and zsh (`zle clear-screen`) with one key combination?

A common way of clearing screen is `^L`, and I tried adding the following to `.tmux.conf`:

```
bind -Troot C-l send-keys C-l\; clear-history
```

So `^L` clears the screen, and clears almost all the history, except that last one screen.

A subsequent `^L` clears it all.

Can the same be achieved with one key combination?

```
bind -Troot C-l send-keys C-l\; clear-history\; send-keys C-l\; clear-history
```

doesn't work. Neither the following does:

```
bind -Troot C-l send-keys C-l C-l\; clear-history
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I ended up doing this differently, from `zsh` itself:

```
# ~/.zshrc
clear-scrollback-and-screen () {
  zle clear-screen
  tmux clear-history
}
zle -N clear-scrollback-and-screen
bindkey -v '^L' clear-scrollback-and-screen
```

For one single reason - I had a C-l mapping in Vim, and the occasional press was clearing Vim screen.

There's a shortcoming to that solution though, it only works in the shell.

Answer (score 8):

Try:

```
bind -n C-k clear-history
```

This binds ctrl-k to the tmux clear-history command. The -n after bind makes it so you don't have to issue the tmux command prefix (ctrl-b by default). I use bash, so ctrl-l already does the equivalent of typing "clear" at the command line. With these two keys I get a nice ctrl-l, ctrl-k combo, which moves all the scroll buffer off the screen (the "clear") and then deletes all that history (the tmux "clear-history" command).

Also, issuing a `send-keys -R` resets (clears) the screen:

```
bind-key b send-keys -R \; clear-history
```

This clears the screen AND the scrollback buffer.

Comment: Worked like a charm, thanks a lot. I ended up with `bind-key -n C-l send-keys -R ^M \; clear-history`. Added `^M` to send a carriage return so that the prompt appears.

From the docs: `bind-key`:  `-n is an alias for -T root`, `send-keys`: `The -R flag causes the terminal state to be reset`.

Answer (score 2):

**The gui solution:**

- On gnome you can setup custom keyboard shortcut to run a custom commands/script [this article](https://docs.fedoraproject.org/en-US/quick-docs/proc_setting-key-shortcut/) explain how to do it
- On KDE you can as well setup custom keyboard shortcut to run a custom command/script [this article](https://www.addictivetips.com/ubuntu-linux-tips/customize-keyboard-shortcuts-on-kde-plasma-5/) explain how to do it

**The shell solution:**

You can use shell alias and function to achieve this to a command... under the file `~/.zshrc`

For instance add this to `~/.zshrc` and restart the shell:

```
c() {
   tmux clear-history
   clear-history
   clear
   reset
}

alias cc='clear'
```

You can then use `c` or `cc` (as a command) to execute what you want.

Comment: did you intend to put `tmux clear-history` inside the function?